# pointer to array c++

Tags: c++

My understanding about assigning an array to a pointer is that the pointer is pointing at the first  index of the array, so when printout the pointer, it should print out the address of the first index of the array, but how come in this case the ***cout*** printed out the value of the whole array? even though I explicitly indicated that I wanted the address of the first index

```
char foo[] = {'A','B','C','\0'};
char* p = foo;
char* q = &(foo[0]);
cout <<"from p:  " << p << endl;
cout << "from q: " <<  q << " " << &(foo[0]) <<  endl;

//output
from p:  ABC
from q: ABC ABC
```

the second question is that I see the difference between those two lines is that one is an array of pointer to char, the other is a pointer to a char array, is that correct? is the parenthesis necessary?

```
 char* bar1[4];
 char (*bar2)[4] = &foo;
 cout << "address of foo is  " << bar2  << endl;
 //output
 address of foo is  0x7fff192f88b0
```

The address of the foo array should be the same as the address of ***A***, right? How do I printout the address of A? since I failed to do so. Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<<` has a dedicated overload for `const char *`, because that's what a C-style string is.  Try this:

```
cout << static_cast<const void *>(bar2) << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I changed the ***foo*** to ***foo={'A','B','C'}*** without the null-terminator, it should be treated as a char array instead of C-string right?

Comment: @ClintHui: No, because the content doesn't affect the type.

Comment: so there is no actual char array in C++, all will be treated as C-String? Thanks

Comment: @ClintHui: `foo` really is a `char` array (it's of type `char [4]`); but in almost all situations it *decays* to `&foo[0]`, i.e. `char *`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to explicitly print out the address of A? Thanks, since the ***<<*** is overloaded.

Comment: @ClintHui: See the example in my answer.

Comment: That should be obvious, a `void*` is not a `char*` so doesn't get treated like one.